# NOTE in R CRAN check ---No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped

Tags: r, package, cran

I have read [NOTE in R CRAN Check: No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164929/note-in-r-cran-check-no-repository-set-so-cyclic-dependency-check-skipped) and to the best of my knowledge followed the suggestions.  Specifically I have an `.Rprofile` file in `~/`  with the line `options(repos = c(CRAN=\"http://cran.r-project.org\")`.  I ran the bash script at the bottom of the page and still have two notes instead of the one I would expect about a New submission.

```
bash-3.2$ ${R} CMD check --as-cran ${name}
* using log directory ‘/private/tmp/deptest.Rcheck’
* using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
* using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘deptest/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘deptest’ version ‘1.0’
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
Maintainer: ‘John Doe <jdoe@doe.net>’
New submission
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... NOTE
  No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
```

Any suggestions how to eliminate the second note about `No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped` when running `R CMD check --as-cran` would be most welcome. I get the same two notes when trying to create a much larger package as well. The same two notes appear when I try to build a package using RStudio as the editor for what that is worth.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2
```

To verify the contents of `.Rprofile` I entered:

```
ip-152010130116:~ alan$ pwd
/Users/alan
ip-152010130116:~ alan$ open -a TextEdit .Rprofile
```

and the single line in `.Rprofile` is

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.r-project.org"))
```

Thanks in advance

What is the likelihood CRAN will accept a package with the `NOTE
  No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped`?

Comment: Does your package modify `options('repose')` at all? If not, this seems like something strange about your setup rather than the package, so I would think it would be accepted by CRAN. You can always put the package on GitHub and run it through travis and/or appveyor and see if the note goes away on those platforms.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. When I run it through `devtools::check(cran = TRUE)`, I get rid of the NOTE though. What exactly is the difference?

Comment: I am having almost the exact same problem.

Comment: My guess is that something on my local machine is not set properly....when I ran my package through the winbilder (http://win-builder.r-project.org/) the message disappeared.  CRAN accepted the package I was originally posting about without complaint.

Answer (score 3):

I had your problem too, and fixed it by adding the following to .Rprofile:

```
 local({r <- getOption("repos"); r["CRAN"] <- "http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/";   options(repos = r)})
```

I think your issue is because you're not pointing to a specific CRAN mirror.
You will want to change the repository to reflect the mirror nearest you.