# CRAN Check: No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I'm aware that my question sounds duplicate to the following two posts:

[NOTE in R CRAN Check: No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164929/note-in-r-cran-check-no-repository-set-so-cyclic-dependency-check-skipped)

[NOTE in R CRAN check ---No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046546/note-in-r-cran-check-no-repository-set-so-cyclic-dependency-check-skipped)

The reason I ask this question again is I don't think answers to the two questions above have solved the problem: I'm going to submit a package to CRAN, and I would like to use `win-builder` from CRAN server to check if my package works for Windows platform. However, there's always a "NOTE: No repository set, so cyclic dependency check skipped". The answers to the above posts indeed work for me when I'm testing on my local Linux and Windows machine. That is, if I edit `~/.Rprofile` and `profile.site`, the problem goes away on my *local* machine. But when I use `devtools::build_win` to check my package, this note appears again, even if I have included the line of rep-setting code in`~/.Rprofile` file in my package.

Therefore, my question is, how can I fix this NOTE when I'm using `devtools::build_win` to run on CRAN win-builder? Thanks!!

Comment: See [this thread on the r-package-devel list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.packages.devel/249) and particularly the reply by the win-builder maintainer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, when I submit my packages, I point out to the CRAN maintainers that I observed the note on win-builder, but not on my local install.  As long as I'm using a recent version of R-devel, they seem to be okay with that.

Comment: @MillerZhu: No problem. I would also (and even somewhat strongly) suggest to ask _packaging and CRAN questions_ on that list rather than here.

Comment: @Benjamin Okay, thanks! That's my case too, and I will make sure to explain to the CRAN maintainers.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! Actually I tried to send two questions to r-package-devel, but the moderator never manually approve my posts, so my messages are still unseen by the list members...

Comment: Sorry about that -- I am one of several admins to that list, and your email was indeed queued.  I just cleared it.